# Run gradle task multiple times

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a gradle project containing two modules in subdirectories. The directory structure is as below.

```
root
    module1
        build.gradle
    module2
        build.gradle
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

The top level `settings.gradle` includes the two modules. The top level `build.gradle` contains the following.

```
task runScript(type: Exec) {
    workingDir 'scripts'
    commandLine 'python3', 'myscript.py'
}

project(':module1') {
    evaluationDependsOn(':module1')

    final test = tasks.findByName('test')
    test.dependsOn(runScript)
}

project(':module2') {
    evaluationDependsOn(':module2')

    final test = tasks.findByName('test')
    test.dependsOn(runScript)
}
```

Task `runScript` sets the database to a known state and **must be run before each module test task**.

When I run the test task my script only executes once. How can I ensure it executes multiple times?

```
$ ./gradlew test 
... some output

:runScript
RUNNING MY SCRIPT

:module1:test
RUNNING MODULE1 TESTS

... some output

:module2:test
RUNNING MODULE2 TESTS
```

### Things I Tried

I tried adding `outputs.upToDateWhen {false}` to the task `runScript` so Gradle never thinks it is up to date. This didn't make any difference; I assume because the task still only occurs once in the task graph?

I tried replacing the lines containing `dependsOn` for each module with `test.doFirst {runScript.execute()}`. This changes when the task gets executed but does not result in multiple executions.

```
$ ./gradlew test 
... some output

:module1:test
RUNNING MY SCRIPT
RUNNING MODULE1 TESTS

... some output

:module2:test
RUNNING MODULE2 TESTS
```

I tried creating a new task for each module. This works but it's duplicating code.

```
project(':module1') {
    evaluationDependsOn(':module1')

    final test = tasks.findByName('test')

    task runScript(type: Exec) {
        workingDir '../scripts'
        commandLine 'python3', 'myscript.py'
    }

    test.dependsOn(runScript)
}

project(':module2') {
    evaluationDependsOn(':module2')

    final test = tasks.findByName('test')

    task runScript(type: Exec) {
        workingDir '../scripts'
        commandLine 'python3', 'myscript.py'
    }

    test.dependsOn(runScript)
}
```

Comment: This won't work. Gradle tasks can only run once in a build. If you need a setup, you should use the `doFirst` method for task-specific setup or the `beforeTest` method for test-specific setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script is necessary for each run of each `Test` task, simply assure its execution before each `Test` task. Why even use a task then?

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        doFirst {
            exec {
                workingDir 'scripts'
                commandLine 'python3', 'myscript.py'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had wanted to define a task to avoid code duplication. In the example I posted all tests needed to run the script. In my real project only a subset run the script as it's expensive and not always necessary. I need to add either a task or an exec to tasks individually.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance :-)

Comment: You can use `tasks.withType(Test).matching { /* any condition */ }` to configure a subset of tasks.