# Gradle: run pre and post tasks also when tasks are chained?

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle

Assume the `build.gradle` at the end of this post.

If I run task `WorkA` **or** `WorkB` I get:

```
> Task :preTask
PreTask
> Task :WorkB (or A)
WorkB (or A)
> Task :finishTask
FinishTask
```

However If run the task `allWork`, **the pre and finish task is only executed once! How to fix this?**

```
> Task :preTask
PreTask
> Task :WorkA
WorkA
> Task :WorkB
WorkB
> Task :finishTask
FinishTask
> Task :AllWork
Combined
```

***build.gradle***

```
task preTask { 
  doFirst { 
     println "PreTask"
  }
}

task finishTask {
  doFirst { 
    println "FinishTask"
  }
}

task WorkA {
  dependsOn preTask
  mustRunAfter preTask
  finalizedBy finishTask
  doFirst { 
   println "WorkA"  
 }
}

task WorkB {
  dependsOn preTask
  mustRunAfter preTask
  finalizedBy finishTask
  doFirst { 
   println "WorkB"  
 }
}

task AllWork {
  dependsOn WorkA
  dependsOn WorkB
  WorkB.mustRunAfter WorkA
  doFirst { 
   println "Combined"  
 }
}
```

Comment: A same task cannot be executed multiple times, see some details here : https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-execute-tasks-multiple-times-in-a-loop/20160/2 .  This is not something you can "fix", as it's Gradle behavior. You should describe more in details your use case, to get some help using other solution(s).

Comment: see also official doc: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html   : "Gradle guarantees that these tasks are executed in the order of their dependencies, and that each task is executed only once. "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run gradle task multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47186324/run-gradle-task-multiple-times)